# Add vertical lines to quantmod::chart_Series

Tags: r, quantmod

I want to add vertical lines on several dates on a certain graph. So far I haven't managed to achieve this simple task. This is what I tried:

```
> s <- get(getSymbols('nvmi'))["2012::"]
> d1 <- index(s[100])
> d1
[1] "2012-05-24"

> chart_Series(s,TA="addLines(v=d1)")
Error in get.current.chob() : improperly set or missing graphics device

> chart_Series(s)
> abline(v=d1) 
# nothing

> add_TA("addLines(v=d1")
Error in `[.data.frame`(lenv$xdata, Env$xsubset) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

From what I have already read here, I know that `abline` is not supposed to work with the new `chart_Series` function. It doesn't seem to work anyway. The `addLines` function does not work in any of the forms I tried - plain `addLines`, `plot(addLines(...))`, `chart_Series(..., TA="addLines(...)")`  or `add_TA("addLines(...)")`.

I need to use the experimental version of quantmod because it solved other problems I had with the old version. `d1` would eventually be a list of dates.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't mix functions from the old and new versions of quantmod's charting functions.  If you want to use `addLines`, you have to use `chartSeries`.  Even if you use `addLines` and `chartSeries`, `d1` should be an xts object, not a datetime object.  For example:

```
library(quantmod)
data(sample_matrix)
s <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
chartSeries(s,TA="addLines(v=s[100])")
```

[image: quantmod::chartSeries]

If you want to add a vertical line using `chart_Series`, create a logical xts object with `TRUE` values where you want the lines to appear and `FALSE` otherwise.  For example:

```
l <- xts(!as.logical(s[,1]),index(s))
l[100] <- TRUE
chart_Series(s,TA="add_TA(l,on=1)")
```

[image: quantmod::chart_Series]

Also note that you can put the vertical line "behind" the chart by using `on=-1` in the `add_TA` call:

```
chart_Series(s,TA="add_TA(l,on=-1,col='grey',border='grey')")
```

Comment: But you add a vertical line here not horizontal one, isn't?

Comment: @agstudy: yes, I assume it was a typo in the OP's title. I have no idea how one could add a horizontal line at specific dates, since the dates are on the x-axis.

Comment: Ok. thanks+1. I see the logic, we superpose only time series(xts objects here) otherwise this will not have "sense".

Comment: @agstudy: Exactly; and it's an easy assumption because `chart_Series` only works on time-series objects.

Comment: Thanks Joshua Ulrich, Exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

add horizontal line my example:

```
library(quantmod)
library(lubridate)

stockId<-"CVS"
showperiod<-6   # 6 months

stockData<-getSymbols(stockId, src="yahoo",auto.assign=FALSE)

startDate<-Sys.Date()-months(showperiod,abbreviate = FALSE)
fromDate<-paste0(year(startDate),month(startDate))

subset<-paste0(fromDate,"/")

mytheme <- chart_theme() 
mytheme$col$dn.col  <- "firebrick1" 
mytheme$col$up.col  <- "darkgreen"
chart_Series(stockData, name = stockId, subset = subset, theme = mytheme)

#if you add line at 2018-6-18 to 2018-07-16 & y(price)=72
#you need creat new data to plot
#
ntick<-nrow(stockData["20180618/20180716"]) #2018-6-18 to 2018-07-16 tick numbers
getDate<-index(stockData["20180618/20180716"])
y<-rep(72,ntick)
df<-data.frame(getDate,y)
linedata<-xts(df$y,order.by = df$getDate)
# add line
add_TA(linedata,on=-1,col="blue",lwd=2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lNts.png)

Comment: Unfortunately add_TA(linedata,on=-1,col="blue",lwd=2) gives me Error in plot.window(c(1, 141), c(NaN, NaN)) : need finite 'ylim' values