# Add vertical line in background in quantmod chart

Tags: r, quantmod

How can I add vertical line to chart in quantmod that appears *in the background*? Consider this example:

```
library(quantmod)
symbol <- "AAPL"
cache <- new.env()
getSymbols(symbol, env=cache)
chartSeries(cache$AAPL, subset="last 3 months")
plot(addLines(v=10)) # Adds vertical line at tick 10.
```

The problem is that adding the vertical line at tick 10 now hides the wicks from the candlestick:

[image: Hidden candlestick wicks]

I also tried the function `addVLine` from `qmao`. It effectively does this:

```
c <- quantmod:::get.current.chob()
i <- index(c@xdata[endpoints(c@xdata, "months")])
plot(addTA(xts(rep(TRUE, length(i)), i), on=-1, col="grey"))
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

While I have the lines in the background now, they are super wide and pretty obtrusive. I just want them in the background in the same way the grid lines already exist there. How can I achieve this?

Note: this question resembles [an existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15384458/1170277), but here I am asking on how to render the vertical line *in the background*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't look at the source code to understand why this works, but it seems to do what you want. Basically, you add the `addLines` call via the `TA` argument to `chartSeries`. This is generally a good thing to do anyway, since it avoids re-drawing the chart for each `add*` call.

```
chartSeries(cache$AAPL, subset="last 3 months", TA="addVo();addLines(v=10,on=-1)")
```

[image]